# Build text wth image inside in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, spannable

I am trying to build a text, that contains a .png inside.
To be more clear I want something like this:
"text text text image text text text"

I tried using StackLayout or Grid, but it does't help because the text is too long and it goes over more lines.
This is the output I am trying to achieve:

[image: output to achieve]

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to use a glyph for the image

Comment: Does this text dynamically change?

Comment: No it does not change dimamically

Comment: Why not create the label line by line? In the third line, use a Horizontal StackLayout to wrap the text and image.

Answer (score 1):

If the text is not dynamically changed, you could create the label line by line.

For example:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="already synchronized at the factory"/>
    <Label Text="which is confirmed by the fact that"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="the icon"/>
        <Image Source="wifi.png" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10"/>
        <Label Text="on the display does not"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label Text="blink. If it does, however, it means that"/>
    <Label Text="a new synchronization is required. To"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Make some slight changes to the margin, padding, height or width to make it look good.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding, the text is acctually changing dinamically :(

Comment: That's okay, then I think you may try Jason's method.